# Strong duality in SDP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

> What can you say  about strong duality if the Slater condition holds for at least one of a primal-dual pair of SDPs?

*My understanding:*

If either the primal or the dual problem is  strictly feasible, then $p^{*}=d^{*}$ i.e, strong duality holds.

Am I correct?

Comment: I had the same question and asked on the Operations Research SE: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/conditions-required-for-strong-duality-to-hold-for-sdps. I haven't gotten a definitive answer though.